# Swift using function from delegated class as selector crashes

Tags: swift, delegates

I have a custom view class, `MyView`, which inherits from `UIView`, and it contains a text field. I have added a `delegate` variable to this class which represents an instance of my `ViewController` class. This controller contains a function which I want to use as a selector in `addTarget` inside `MyView`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let my_view = MyView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.my_view.delegate = self
        self.my_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(self.my_view)

        // set up constraints
    }

    func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd h:mm a"
        self.my_view.time_text_field.text = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date))"
    }

}

class MyView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: ViewController! {
        didSet {
            self.time_text_field.delegate = self.delegate
        }
    }

    lazy var time_text_field: UITextField = {
        let text_field = UITextField()

        let date_picker = UIDatePicker()
        date_picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.delegate.handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        text_field.inputView = date_picker

        text_field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return text_field
    }()

    init() {
        self.addSubview(self.time_text_field)

        // set up constraints
    }

}
```

When the function `handleDatePicker` gets called, the app crashes. However, when I move the function into the `MyView` class, the app no longer crashes:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate  {

    let my_view = MyView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.my_view.delegate = self
        self.my_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(self.my_view)

        // set up constraints
    }

}

class MyView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: ViewController! {
        didSet {
            self.time_text_field.delegate = self.delegate
        }
    }

    lazy var time_text_field: UITextField = {
        let text_field = UITextField()

        let date_picker = UIDatePicker()
        date_picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        text_field.inputView = date_picker

        text_field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return text_field
    }()

    init() {
        self.addSubview(self.time_text_field)

        // set up constraints
    }

    func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd h:mm a"
        self.time_text_field.text = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date))"
    }

}
```

Why does the app crash when the function used in `#selector` comes from the delegated class? Thanks.

Comment: what is the comment on crash?

Comment: Please add the error stack trace. If the app crashes - it will have a stack trace. It is always nice to have as much information as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was writing

```
date_picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.delegate.handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Instead of `self` for the first parameter, I should be using `self.delegate`:

```
date_picker.addTarget(self.delegate, action: #selector(self.delegate.handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```